# SQL SERVER T-SQL Calculate SubTotal and Total by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subtotal, rollup

I am trying to add subtotal by group and total to a table. I've recreated the data using the following sample.

```
DECLARE @Sales TABLE(
        CustomerName  VARCHAR(20),
        LegalID VARCHAR(20),
        Employee VARCHAR(20),
        DocDate DATE,
        DocTotal Int,
        DueTotal Int
)
INSERT INTO @Sales SELECT 'Jhon Titor','12345', 'Employee1','2015-09-01',1000,200 
INSERT INTO @Sales SELECT 'Jhon Titor','12345', 'Employee1','2015-08-20',500,100
INSERT INTO @Sales SELECT 'Jhon Titor','12345', 'Employee1','2015-08-18',200,50 
INSERT INTO @Sales SELECT 'Deli Armstrong','2345', 'Employee1','2015-09-17',2300,700
INSERT INTO @Sales SELECT 'Deli Armstrong','2345', 'Employee1','2015-09-11',5000,1000
INSERT INTO @Sales SELECT 'Ali Mezzu','6789', 'Employee1','2015-09-07',300,200
```

Selecting `@Sales`

[image]

I need to add the customer subtotal just below customer occurrences and total in the end row of table like this:

[image]

what I've tried so far:

```
select 
    case 
        when GROUPING(CustomerName) = 1 and
             GROUPING(Employee) = 1 and 
             GROUPING(DocDate) = 1 and
             GROUPING(LegalID) = 0 then 'Total ' + CustomerName

        when GROUPING(CustomerName) = 1 and
             GROUPING(Employee) = 1 and
             GROUPING(DocDate) =1 and
             GROUPING(LegalID) = 1 then 'Total'

        else CustomerName end as CustomerName,
    LegalID, Employee,DocDate,
    sum(DocTotal) as DocTotal,
    sum(DueTotal) as DueTotal 
From @Sales 
group by LegalID, CustomerName,Employee,DocDate with rollup
```

But I am getting subtotal as null where it should say `Total Jhon Titor` as I set it static in the query, also it is repeated for every not aggregated column (3),

[image]

How can I add subtotal and total to the table presented above?

I am open to use a query without ROLLUP operator. I think it is possible using unions but don't know how to start.

Thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select (case when GROUPING(CustomerName) = 0 and
                  GROUPING(Employee) = 1 and 
                  GROUPING(DocDate) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(LegalID) = 1
             then 'Total ' + CustomerName
             when GROUPING(CustomerName) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(Employee) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(DocDate) =1 and
                  GROUPING(LegalID) = 1 then 'Total'
             else CustomerName
        end) as CustomerName,
       LegalID, Employee,DocDate,
       sum(DocTotal) as DocTotal,
       sum(DueTotal) as DueTotal 
From @Sales 
group by grouping sets((LegalID, CustomerName ,Employee, DocDate),
                       (CustomerName),
                       ()
                      );
```

Comment: It works, tested with 224 rows and takes less time than `UNION` solution proposed by @GiorgiosBetsos. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT CustomerName, LegalID, Employee, DocDate, DocTotal, DueTotal
FROM (       
  SELECT CustomerName AS cName, CustomerName, 
         LegalID, Employee, DocDate, DocTotal, DueTotal,
         1 AS ord
  FROM Sales

  UNION ALL

  SELECT CustomerName AS cName, CONCAT('Total ', CustomerName), 
         NULL, NULL, NULL, 
         SUM(DocTotal), SUM(DueTotal), 2 AS ord
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY CustomerName

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT 'ZZZZ' AS cName, 'Total', NULL, NULL, NULL, 
         SUM(DocTotal), SUM(DueTotal), 3 AS ord
  FROM Sales ) AS t
ORDER BY cName, ord
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eaf83/7)